# Midrule that extends only over some of the columns in booktabs

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

I hope this isn't a silly question, the thing is that I want to create a table with a midrule applied in just some cells, I mean something like that (just between Item, Animal and Description):

[image]

I've always used the comand `midrule` in order to insert a horizontal line in the table, but it is always applied to the whole row and thats just what I don't want to.

I hope somebody could help me out.

Answer (score 60):

`booktabs` provides the command `\cmidrule` for rules that extend over only certain columns.  One example would be:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \toprule
  A & B & C \\
  \cmidrule{1-2}
  D & E & F\\
  \cmidrule(lr{1em}){2-3}
  G & H & I\\
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-1}
  J & H & K\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The general syntax is

```
\cmidrule[thickness](shortening){colstart-colend}
```

where `shortening` specifies which end(s) `l` left or `r` right should be shortened.  As standerd the shortening amount is `0.5em` when `l` or `r` is specified; it can be changed for a given end by writing e.g. `r{1em}` instead of `r`.

The table in your example is exactly one of the examples in the [`booktabs` manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), which also contains the code to generate it, see the top of page 5.

Comment: +1! Is there a similar command \ctoprule and/or \cbottomrule?

Comment: @JimmyR. Thank you.  No these don't exist.  For full width you can pass a thickness argument to all rules, e.g. `\toprule[5pt]`.  For partial width I would want to see a sensible use case before suggesting a solution.