# How do I force my figures to fit the page or the text width?

Tags: floats

I have this figure generated by the following code. It is overflowing. How do I make it fit the page width?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularray} % https://www.latex-tables.com/#
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=g going right,node distance=1mm, 
        nodes={inner sep=0,on chain}]
    \node[anchor=south west] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,trim={0 50 0 0},clip]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \draw (g-begin.north west|-g-end.north)+(0,1mm) -- ([xshift=-5cm,yshift=1mm]g-end.north east);
    \draw (g-begin.north west|-g-end.north)+(8cm,0mm) -- ([xshift=0,yshift=0mm]g-end.north east);
    \node[] at (3cm,2cm) {Reconstruct};
    \node[] at (8cm,2cm) {Forecast};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Given the historical human and object motion}
    \label{fig:intro}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I included the textwidth variable but it does not work.

```
\begin{figure}[width=\textwidth]
...
...
...
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Instead of using 6 times .2\textwidth, choose a width which will add up to 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there is more going on, I think a simple table should be enough to solve your problem

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*6{X}@{}}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Reconstruct} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Forecast} \\
    \midrule
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Given the historical human and object motion}\label{fig:intro}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow that is significantly easier to read ! Just one question, how can I "cut" the midrule in the middle as it should not be a single continuous line. In the code I have above I had to manually search for the right value through trial and error. The custom midrule length only lets me have 1 midrule per line https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482214/custom-midrule-length

Comment: Np, in the code, change `\midrule` to `\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r{2pt}){1-3} \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l{2pt}){4-6}`. The part `[...]` sets thickness of the rule and `\lightrulewidth` is equivalent to `\midrule`. You could also try `\heavyrulewidth` or `\cmidrulewidth` (default) or just use numerics such as `1.2pt`. More info in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Comment: thank you so much !